# Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "Unable to add global "ea" as the runtime or the extensions

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4, easyadmin, easyadmin3

In browser, easyadmin is working fine. But when I run test case which asserts redirection logic to EasyAdmin's dashboard controller after login, it failed with the following error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "Unable to add global "ea" as the runtime or the extensions
```

As it's pointed out in the following comment,
https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/5591#issuecomment-1405962016
It seems to me that EasyAdmin twig extension is called after Twig extensions and runtime are initialized

easyadmin twig extension shouldn't be called before extensions and runtime are initialized and phpunit should pass

Comment: How are you generating your url in your test case

Comment: I'm not generating admin url in test manually. The request is sent on test using `client->submit()` method and request redirection is handled by controller

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution to my problem.

When multiple requests are executed in one test, since Symfony 5.4 the `Client`
reboots the Kernel for each request. So to be able to run several request
in the test, I should have added `$this->client->enableReboot();` in the test cases which execute several requests.

> Multiple Requests in One Test
> After making a request, subsequent requests will make the client reboot the kernel. This recreates the container from scratch to ensures that requests are isolated and use new service objects each time. This behavior can have some unexpected consequences: for example, the security token will be cleared, Doctrine entities will be detached, etc.

Here is the link https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#multiple-requests-in-one-test